# Is Angular Material being actively developed for Angular 4

Tags: angular-material2

Hi hope this isn't too vague but I have some technical-ish bits also. I'm starting a new front end project (which needs to be responsive and work on mobile as well as desktop) and I'm not so strong on FE technologies being more of a .NET / back end developer.

I've been reading up on Angular Material and it sounds like the mutt's nuts but I can't really see if it's being actively developed and how big the user community is for it. I've googled it several times and I see samples for Angular 1.x but doesn't seem to be much for Angular 4. From the github site it says its in beta now but I'm not seeing huge amounts of love for it, which is strange given that it's from google.

So my questions:

- is Angular Material being actively developed?
- how big is the user community?
- is it technically easier or more difficult that say Bootstrap?
- are there any major pain points with it? I'm seeing things like styling / theming that could be problematic?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

is Angular Material being actively developed?
- from what I heard its actively under development, but it seems slow, to use a stable version it will take another year, that is my opinion

how big is the user community?
- its big, loads of developers already using it and its actively under development and updates

is it technically easier or more difficult that say Bootstrap?
I have been currently using this framework and I can say its not that hard compare to Bootstrap, just some docs on Material 2 are not well documented and missing features

are there any major pain points with it? I'm seeing things like styling / theming that could be problematic?

the only problem that I faced, some components are missing, not all features are implemented, hard to modify some components. For that reason I am not going to use it for a development in my project and going to use more stable framework like PrimeNG, which I am testing at the moment.

I really like Material 2, but would not risk to use it for a real project yet. Some components are really cool, if you want you can use some of them, and if you need more you can combine them with another UI framework.

Comment: Have a look at PrimeNG if you are going to use Angular 4. Also if you like Material Design, but don't want to go with Angular you can use React or Vue.js, they also have Material Design components